# eBay API: ReviseItemRequest and removing Item.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions

Tags: ebay-api

Due to [this](https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/627/kw/Local%20pickup/)

For enable *Local Pickup Only* shipping we don't require insert "ShippingDetails" container into request.

It's work ok for *ListItem*, but have some problem on *ReviseItem*

For example:
1) We *List* item with specified Shipping. For example:

```
<ShippingDetails>
     <ShippingServiceOptions>
       <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
       <ShippingServiceCost>0</ShippingServiceCost>
        <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
     </ShippingServiceOptions>
     <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
</ShippingDetails>
```

2) After that we try to *Revise* item, remove all shipping information and activate "Local Pickup Only"

**First variant:**

Don't specify *ShippingDetails*, send only *ShipToLocations* only

```
<ShipToLocations>None</ShipToLocations>
```

eBay return errors like: 
"At least one valid shipping service must be specified"

**Second variant:**

Specify empty ShippingDetails or ShippingDetails with some shipping method (I use 'LocalDelivery'). And still no luck.

Are there any solution to activate "Local Pickup Only" shipping after item was listed with some Domestic & International shippings methods.

I would appreciate for any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an eBay API specific question, I recommend you to ask this question on [eBay developer community](http://developer.ebay.com/community/forums/), they are awesome, you will get a reply very quickly!